# PHP Searching for a value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm having trouble finding out how to search a particular array for an index / matching value.

I can get everything listed and formatted but I'm not sure exacty what's going on (it doesn't seem like an array in array, or is it?) and can't figure out how to do a search for a specific index / value in this particular case.

Example:

```
{
  "AppName": {
    "date": "20230801",
    "version": "6.8.48"
  },
  "Invoices": [
    {
      "Administration": {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "TEST",
        "description": "Test Administration"
      },
      "Invoice": {
        "id": 4350,
        "type": "",
        "invoiceNumber": 2340323,
        "date": "2023-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "dueDate": "2023-08-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "amount": 196.3
      },
      "Relation": {
        "nr": 102616,
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      "TermsOfPayment": {
        "id": 11,
        "description": "Prepayment"
      }
    },
    {
      "Administration": {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "TEST",
        "description": "Test Administration"
      },
      "Invoice": {
        "id": 4351,
        "type": "",
        "invoiceNumber": 2340324,
        "date": "2023-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "dueDate": "2023-08-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "amount": 748.3
      },
      "Relation": {
        "nr": 102158,
        "name": "Jane Doe"
      },
      "TermsOfPayment": {
        "id": 11,
        "description": "Prepayment"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

For listing values I use:

```
$parsed = json_decode($received, true);

if ($parsed['AppName'] == true) {

    $obj = json_decode($received);

    $invoices = $obj->Invoices;

    foreach ($invoices as $key => $value) {
        $invoice_number = $value->Invoice->invoiceNumber;
        $invoice_amount = $value->Invoice->amount;

        print "<br>".$invoice_number;
        print "<br>".$invoice_amount."<br>";
    }
```

Now the next step is searching the amount for a particular invoice number.  So searching for 2340324 needs to return 748.3

I tried searching / matching keys using array_search and array_column but all I get is empty values.  I must be doing something wrong and I guess it has something to do with the "array depth"?

Any pointers on how to handle this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you decoding the same JSON string twice, instead of reusing the result?

Comment: And probably for similar reasons: stray comma in the JSON Text and $parsed['AppName'] is never truthy for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you tried array_column() and array_search(). Good nose.

And good news: We search the truth in array_column() as the invoice numbers are unique natural numbers, so we can use the indexing feature of array_column().

But beforehand, what you should always consider first is to do it with foreach:

```php
$amount = null;
foreach ($obj->Invoices as $invoice) {
    if (2340324 === $invoice->Invoice->invoiceNumber) {
        $amount = $invoice->Invoice->amount;
        break;
    }
}
# $amount: 748.3
```

Now with this out of the way, let's see how to do it with functions.

### array_column()

Given `$received` is corrected for the stray comma as json_decode() does not support that:

```php
$obj = json_decode($received, false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

The first parameter of array_column() is always what to traverse/index (subject) and named $array. (Since PHP 7.0.0 supports objects as well.)

The second is what to return as array values and named $column_key.

And the third is what value to use as index and named $index_key.

The return type is always array.

We could then, only with array_column(), create an array of all invoice amounts indexed by invoice numbers, and then use array access of 2340324 to get the amount:

```php
$amount = array_column(
    array: array_column(
        array: $obj->Invoices,
        column_key: 'Invoice'
    ),
    column_key: 'amount',
    index_key: 'invoiceNumber',
)[2340324] ?? null;
```

So the answer is array_column() twice. First to obtain the array of invoices and second to index/map the amounts by/to invoiceNumber.

If you feel this code is hard to read (follow), you can use some intermediate variables and re-arrange:

```php
$invoices = array_column($obj->Invoices, 'Invoice');

$invoiceAmountsByInvoiceNumber = array_column($invoices, 'amount', 'invoiceNumber');

$amount = $invoiceAmountsByInvoiceNumber[2340324] ?? null;

# $amount: 748.3
```

Or use the foreach approach as it has less indirection.

https://php.net/array_column

### Notes

The JSON Text is with typed objects¹ and object collections, this makes traversing it hard, as it adds to the recursion depth and you will always need to go one extra level deeper.

Therefore, to search for a scalar value will always require to map it's property.

The standard operation can not be directly applied and it needs array_column() two times, first to build the array of objects, then to do the standard search: [*"Most efficient way to search for object in an array by a specific property's value"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7106772/367456);

---

¹ *typed objects* I call them by this name, I don't know where the convention stems from or what other naming exists. I'm open for comments in this regard.

Comment: I hadn't even thought about the foreach option which seems perfectly usefull in this case.
Based on your excellent explanation I can even do some more improvements thank you!

PS: When I use the invoice number as a variable it only works with Equal comparision and not Identical.  Could using Equal for this cause any issues down the road?

Comment: Variable: $number = "2340324"; | Comparison: if ($number === $invoice->Invoice->invoiceNumber) | PHP Version: 7.4

Comment: Alright, there it is: `$number = 2340324`, the invoice-number in the JSON Text is a natural number and in the decoded PHP stdClass object property then an integer. Ensure `$number` is integer, too, not string as you have it in your comment. Do you need to support 32bit architectures? and what is the value range for the invoice-numbers? https://php.net/integer  ,   https://php.net/string